# How to enable logging on influxdb to a file in docker

Tags: docker, logging, dockerfile, influxdb

I have influxdb running using docker and currently logs can be seen only by docker logs command but I want the logs in /var/log/file.log how can I achieve it.

I tried adding

```
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/influx.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/error.log
```

in the docker file but it seems not woking.

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly what you want but I think you need to change the logging driver to achieve this. Have a look here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

Answer (score -1):

The path : "/var/log/file.log" you are talking about, it is inside your machine or the container ?

If you are talking about the path inside the container, you can try docker exec "container name" ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/influx.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/error.log.

If you are talking about the path inside your machine, you should give the docker daemon the right to  write inside /var/log/ and you should configure the "volume" section of your docker compose file.

Comment: I have given it as the path inside but there are no logs in the file that's the problem

Comment: Did you try to execute the command : docker-compose exec "container name" ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/influx.log \ && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/error.log ?